# Enforcing Order of Execution (stage progression) in picklist

Tags: visualforce, picklist

How to force the order of execution(selection) of the picklist values in salesforce.Is there any other way other than validation rules in visualforce page.

Lets say I have 4 picklist values  (Draft,Rep Input,Rep Ack,Completed) on Status field.I want to force the users to go through each stage before it gets to 'Completed' status.

The process is similar to opportunity stage

Comment: If you need control of what is surfaced to the user through the UI, then you need Visualforce. Visualforce really the best avenue for "native" interface UI control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The enforcement of stage progression is most easily done using validation rules with the `ISCHANGED` and `PRIORVALUE` functions. The validation rule will enforce stage progress based on the current and prior picklist value.

This example validation rule should enforce the progress from `Draft` to `Rep Input` to `Rep Ack` to `Completed` and nothing is allowed to be reverted back to `Draft` status. (The first `AND` from "not draft" to "draft" might need to be altered to handle a blank value, but it demonstrates the idea.)

As Mike noted in his answer, this methodology only forces the user to save the record multiple times with picklist values in a specific order - it doesn't truly enforce anything. Though maybe this is exactly what you're looking to do here.

One thing to note, this is not just a VF solution. It works in all cases - VF, native pages, data loader, batches, etc. since it's enforced at the record level when the database commit takes place.

**Error Formula**

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED( Status ),
    OR(
        AND(
            NOT(ISPICKVAL( PRIORVALUE( Status ), "Draft" )),
            ISPICKVAL( Status, "Draft" )
        ),
        AND(
            NOT(ISPICKVAL( PRIORVALUE( Status ), "Draft" )),
            ISPICKVAL( Status, "Rep Input" )
        ),
        AND(
            NOT(ISPICKVAL( PRIORVALUE( Status ), "Rep Input" )),
            ISPICKVAL( Status, "Rep Ack" )
        ),
        AND(
            NOT(ISPICKVAL( PRIORVALUE( Status ), "Rep Ack" )),
            ISPICKVAL( Status, "Completed" )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Validation rules could help, but the would not really be enforceable. A user could save the record as the next step and then keep updating the steps, one save at a time. This is more of a user training problem and not something the technology can solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger, but it is worse than a validation rule. So validation rule is Ok.

I just can not understand why this is necessary. You can create Visualforce [wizard](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_wizard.htm) to provide 4-step process. In this case, the user will not be able to skip any step. Instead, an administrator can create a record using APEX with Completed status.

Comment: I cannot use visualforce wizard.My process is similar to Opportunity Stage